# What is the best approach to using videos to animate a weapons' display screen in Unity?

Tags: shaders, textures, materials, video

My job is to create, model and animate sci-fi weapons', and create Unity assets out of them so they are ready to use.

This particular weapon has two side displays. I've animated some text in After Effects and exported them as MP4 files to be used as emission maps. There is a separate file for each state of the gun, such as, "CHARGING", "READY', "SCANNING", etc. When I export it as an FBX from Blender, everything loads fine, except for the video texture (which is being used as an emission map).

I need to be able to load the video as an emission map for the display panels of the gun, keeping the UV Mapping I created in Blender. I also need to be able to change the video on the fly to reflect the state the gun is in.

This part is new to me, and I don't know where to begin. Normally, I can drag and drop files into Unity, but it is not showing the video file as a texture when I try to assign it.

Is there an addon that can make the process easier? Is this something that requires a script, or can it be done with something already built into Unity?

Comment: Myself, I would not use a weapon asset that needed a video file. That sounds more expensive that necessary. Would it be possible to achieve the same look with a shader effect? (Showing us the appearance you're trying to achieve can help us advise on this)

Comment: @DMGregory Sure, here's the side of one of the gun's displays.  https://1drv.ms/v/s!Auf81kbPTMG1iYlnQKgO6EApaf_9Cg?e=EzQ2GL   In this example, the text animates onto the screen and then animates off.  I have a video file for each text.

Comment: @DMGregory If it's going to be too expensive then I'll need to do something else.  There could be 10-20 players at one time using the same gun.  Would it be a better way, to use still images and just swap out the images instead?  I don't know much of Unity, I just do the models, but I can maybe learn what I need to get it done.  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I think this would be better accomplished by a shader. You could have all of the text in one texture, and use material parameters to control which text is displayed and how far along in its animation it should be.